# if profile id = 1 include no profile.php?

Tags: php, mysql

can someone help i have users on my site and when a user clicks on their profile it takes the user to profile.php?id=(whatever id number)

I am trying to make it so that if a user tries to go to profile id= '1' then this will include noprofile.php basically telling the user that profile doesnt exist.

I have been doing this which seemed to work but now for whatever reson after a couple of days its stopped working and im not sure why?

Can someone show me where im going wrong thanks.

code in profile.php:

```
<?php
$admin_account = admin_account();
while ($admin = mysql_fetch_array($admin_account)) {
    include ('includes/mod_profile/mod_noprofile.php');

}
?>
```

function:

```
function admin_account() {
            global $connection;
            global $profile_id;
            $query = "SELECT user_id
                        FROM ptb_profiles
                        WHERE user_id =\"$profile_id\"
                        AND ptb_profiles.user_id='1'";
            $admin_account = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($query, $connection);
            return $admin_account;
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain select query a bit more, I don't understant what this means: `WHERE user_id = \"$profile_id\" AND ptb_profiles.user_id='1'` ? Do you mean user_id must be equal to $profile_id and '1' same time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing in *profile.php*. You want to show *mod_noprofile.php* if `$profile_id` is 1 or the query returns nothing? What you are actually doing is showing *mod_noprofile.php* if a profile is found (using a while instead of an if).

Comment: I also hope you are at least escaping `$profile_id` somewhere in your code with `intval()` or `filter_input()` to make sure nobody is using this query for SQL injection. It would be even better to use a prepared statement here...

Answer (score -1):

Do a test before you execute the query to see if the id==1

```
if isset($_GET["id"]==1){
    include ('includes/mod_profile/mod_noprofile.php');
}
else {
    //do query and get user profile information
}
```